Unir dos tablas pero saber de que tabla trae cada registro
Necesito unir dos tablas para hacer un reporte, cada tabla trae los mismos campos, Id, referencia, fecha y hora, pero necesito saber de que tabla es cada registro que trae.
SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora FROM ( 
    SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora FROM entradas 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora FROM salidas as salidas 
)as tbl;

Actualmente queda algo así, pero necesito que me ponga como ahí si es entrada o salida.


Un comentario lateral, ya que no se ve más contexto, no hace falta hacer un select from  una unión, el código es más difícil de leer y no encuentro una razón para mantenerlo (las tablas derivadas son muy útiles, pero su caso de uso suele ser en sentencias más complejas). Sugiero que, en aras de la legibilidad, consideres quitar el select más externo y quedarte solo con la unión de las tablas. Saludos.

En el mismo select de cada consulta proyecta un campo con el texto que desees:
SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora, Campo as Campo FROM 
( 
    SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora, "Entrada" as Campo FROM entradas 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Referencia as Referencia, Fecha as Fecha, Hora as Hora, "Salida" as Campo FROM salidas as salidas 
)as tbl;

Aquí pones el texto "Entrada" o "Salida" en dependencia de la consulta, y ambas columnas tendrán el nombre Campo como alias, para que pueda ser igualmente proyectado en la consulta más general.
